# How to group a query and get n th items per group randomly

Tags: mysql, arraylist, silverstripe

i 've got a table Bildergalerie. Each record has a correspondending page (PageID). How can i loop over the table and query 4 records randomly per each PageID (grouping?) and pass the result to the template?

```
**ID ClassName PageID**
1 Bildergalerie **8**
2 Bildergalerie **12**
3 Bildergalerie 13
4 Bildergalerie 13
5 Bildergalerie 13
6 Bildergalerie 13
7 Bildergalerie 13
8 Bildergalerie 13
9 Bildergalerie 13
10 Bildergalerie 13
11 Bildergalerie 8
12 Bildergalerie 8
13 Bildergalerie 12
14 Bildergalerie 12
15 Bildergalerie 12
16 Bildergalerie 12
17 Bildergalerie 12
18 Bildergalerie 12
19 Bildergalerie 12
20 Bildergalerie 12
21 Bildergalerie 12
22 Bildergalerie 12
23 Bildergalerie 12
24 Bildergalerie 12
25 Bildergalerie 12
```

Hope anybody can help. THX :-)

At the moment i use the following function within the controller

```
public function getBildergalerieninner() { 
    $Testimonials = Bildergalerie::get()->sort('RAND()')->limit(12);
    return $Testimonials;
}
```

In the template i use this loop

```
<% loop Bildergalerieninner %>
    <div class="grids col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 mix all $Page.URLSegment">
        <div class="grid">
            <img src="$Bildergalerie.BildergalerieThumb.URL" width="400" height="273" alt="$Alttext" class="img-responsive" />
            <div class="figcaption">
            <h4>$Alttext</h4>
            <a href="$Bildergalerie.BildergalerieBig.URL" data-rel="prettyPhoto[portfolio]">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </a> 
            <% if VerlinkungID %>
            <a href="$Verlinkung.Link">
                <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
            </a>
            <% end_if %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<% end_loop %>
```

What i try to do is to get randomly for Bildergalerie items per PageID ?

i had already a look into other questions, but didn't find an answer or a way to get into the right direction?!

Comment: can you show your expected output here ?

Comment: What have you tried and why did it fail? There are many questions and answers(!) on sql and grouping on this site already. Which ones did you look at? Please don't just dump your work on us. Asking good questions implies some research on your side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage it easily with a GroupedList with Silverstripe:

```
public function GroupedEntries() {
        return GroupedList::create(
            Bildergalerie::get()->sort('RAND()')
        );
}

<% loop $GroupedEntries.GroupedBy('PageID') %>
<% loop $Children.Limit(4) %>
<div class="grids col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 mix all $Page.URLSegment">
    <div class="grid">
        <img src="$Bildergalerie.BildergalerieThumb.URL" width="400" height="273" alt="$Alttext" class="img-responsive" />
        <div class="figcaption">
        <h4>$Alttext</h4>
        <a href="$Bildergalerie.BildergalerieBig.URL" data-rel="prettyPhoto[portfolio]">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </a> 
        <% if VerlinkungID %><a href="$Verlinkung.Link">
            <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
        </a><% end_if %></div>
    </div>
</div>
<% end_loop %>
<% end_loop %>
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit tricky, but not impossible to do it with single SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    id, classname, pageid
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        *, @row:=IF(pageid=@pageid, @row, 0) + 1 AS rn, @pageid:=pageid 
    FROM 
        (SELECT *, RAND() AS trand FROM bildergalerie) t1,
        (SELECT @row:=0, @pageid:='') sqlvars 
    ORDER BY 
        pageid, trand
) t2
WHERE rn <= 4
```

This gives you random four records per `pageid` group combined in one resultset.

Comment: Thank you for spending your time and your fast reply. I just found an easy way :-)

Comment: Great! Mark any answer in order to close the topic.

Comment: it seems that i have to wait two days to mark my own answer :-)